How does Java map filesystem paths to Unicode?
In Rust, OS file paths are stored using a specific Path type instead of a str. That's because str represents a UTF-8 sequence of bytes, while kernels either don't enforce any kind of encoding (Unix) as long as the slash is represented with its ASCII codepoint, or are encoded in a 16-bit encoding (Windows).
In Java, paths are represented using the String type in the standard library, which internally uses UCS-2. This is not implementation-specific since some String methods "leak" this encoding one way or another.
How does Java manage to represent Unix' arbitrary byte sequence paths as Unicode? I assume that it treats paths as being ASCII or UTF-8 in order to map "raw" bytes to Unicode codepoints since paths are in practice almost always ASCII or UTF-8, but what if there's a sequence of bytes that isn't valid ASCII nor UTF-8? Is the conversion to Unicode/UCS-2 lossless? Is there a documented algorithm to go back-and-forth? Anything I should consider when dealing with file paths in Java if I don't want to exclude non-latin alphabet users?
Example

Go in an empty directory
Type touch $(echo -e "\xc3\x28"). This will create a perfectly valid file with a name that cannot be represented in Unicode.
Open jshell
Type new File(".").listFiles()[0].isFile()

This returns false
If you look at the path of the listed file, it contains a U+FFFD codepoint followed by the \x28, meaning that \xC3 has been lossyly converted into Unicode and doesn't represent the actual path anymore




Your Question is not clear. A major plank in the design of Java as a platform is that you are insulated from details of the host OS. That includes details about the file system employed by the host OS. If you are using the bundled Java classes to interact with files (tip: NIO.2), then you need not care about the bits and bytes internal to the host OS’s file system. Dealing with those file system details is the job of (a) the people authoring the OS and (b) the people authoring the Java implementation such as OpenJDK. Part of the joy of Java is not dealing with such matters.

@BasilBourque This makes no sense. You can't just not care about how a String will be encoded in the file system. If a path represented as UCS-2 was treated as-is bit-for-bit when opening a file, then the path corresponding to the Java String "/tmp/file" would actually not be the "/tmp/file" any other Unix program would expect (there would be interleaved zeros). It's cool that Java abstracts away some complexity, but you can't act like encoding doesn't exist or matter. This philosophy leads to programs breaking down when foreign users dare to use their local alphabet.

What is a non-unicode character BTW? A byte sequence that is illegal in unicode, or just a random byte sequence that might/might not be valid unicode?

@queeg I wrote it this way to make the title shorter, but I admit it could've been clearer. What I meant is a byte sequence that can't be interpreted as ASCII or UTF-8, like "\xc3\x28", so re-encoding it as UCS-2 would be either lossy or require a special substitution

To avoid doubt, could you show the cmd/bash/terminal command that creates a filename of a format you cannot access in Java?

@DuncG touch $(echo -e "\xc3\x28") (touch (echo -e "\xc3\x28") in fish) would create a file that, if listed with File.listFiles(), cannot be opened because it contains a Unicode replacement character instead of the first \xc3 which cannot be represented in Unicode.

@MrAnima Works fine for me, though I am using WSL on Windows 11 and so didn't expect to see any failures.

Your Question is not clear, but here goes.
I assume by "non-unicode" you actually meant "not in Java’s internal character encoding".
There is almost no such thing as a non-Unicode character. Unicode 15.1 represents 149,813 characters, virtually all characters used by humans, including past and present, "living" and "dead" languages & scripts, as identified by academics and authorities. Plus a mess of emojis ‍♂️. As the more obscure characters are identified, Unicode grows.
A major plank in the design of Java as a platform is that you are insulated from details of the host OS.
That includes details about the file system employed by the host OS. If you are using the bundled Java classes to interact with files (tip: NIO.2), then you need not care about the bits and bytes internal to the host OS’s file system. Dealing with those file system details is the job of (a) the people authoring the OS and (b) the people authoring the Java implementation such as OpenJDK. Part of the joy of Java is not dealing with such matters.
For example, I created a nested hierarchy of folders in the Finder.app of macOS Sonoma 14.4.1. I used Google Translate to translate the word "apple" in Russian, "banana" in Romanian, "carrot" in Japanese. Into that folder I created a plain text file in UTF-8 encoding with a name of "data" in French. That file contains one lin: Bonjour!.

Using Java NIO.2, I represent the path to that file with a Path object via the Paths (plural) class.
final String HOME = System.getProperty( "user.home" );  // /Users/basil_dot_work for me on macOS.
final Path path = Paths.get( HOME, "Яблоко" , "Banană" , "にんじん" , "données.txt" ); // Apple in Russian, Banana in Romanian, Carrot in Japanese.

The point here is that I have no idea how Apple engineers encode the various languages in the various folder names. And I do not care. Java takes care of interacting with the macOS file system on my behalf. That it works is thanks to the Apple developers and any others who have contributed to the macOS branch of the OpenJDK project.
All I needed to do was represent the Unicode characters in UTF-8 encoding in my .java source file of my Java code. The compiler used by my IDE (IntelliJ) knows how to parse UTF-8, and then encode as Java bytecode. At runtime, the JVM deciphered the intended text in that bytecode to represent text in some internally-defined encoding. (By the way, Java’s internally-defined encoding is not necessarily UCS-2. As I vaguely recall, modern JVM implementations may use something more efficient for Latin-oriented content. Again, I do not care — that's the benefit of Java.)
Next I open that file using Files.lines to read a Stream of the lines, each a String object.
try
{
    Files
            .lines( path , StandardCharsets.UTF_8 )
            .forEach( System.out :: println );
} catch ( IOException e )
{
    throw new RuntimeException( e );
}

Result when running in Java 22:

Bonjour!

Now we can take that exact same compiled class to a Linux machine, and be confident it will run successfully. The JVM specific to Linux will know how to mediate between our bytecode-encoded folder/file names and the Linux file system’s own encoding of those same Unicode characters.

"Java takes care of interacting with the macOS file system on my behalf" I get that, but in your example, macOS requires file paths to be UTF-8, so I'm guessing Java can simply transform UTF-8 into its internal format, whichever it is, as long as it can be mapped to Unicode codepoints. But what if you're on Linux, where paths are raw byte sequences? Are these byte sequences arbitrarily assumed to be UTF-8? What if they contain an invalid byte combination under the rules of UTF-8?

"macOS requires file paths to be UTF-8," No, we do not know that. The Finder.app accepts a paste of text in UTF-8 format. But that can be translated into any possible encoding in the underlying file system. I have no idea what is the underlying character encoding for file and folder names in the Apple File System (APFS) used by Apple on my Mac. Any JVM built for macOS translates that file system specific encoding to the Java internal encoding.

"on Linux, where paths are raw byte sequences" — All text is ultimately "raw byte sequences". How you make sense of those bytes is what defines an encoding such as UTF-8.

How you map these byte sequences to Unicode codepoints is defined by an encoding. But Linux doesn't specify an encoding for file paths. If programs want to cooperate, they have to agree on an encoding, because the sequence "foo" will be 3 bytes long in ASCII/UTF-8 but 6 bytes long in a 16 bit encoding. I'm pretty certain that Java also treats Unix paths as UTF-8 because that's the most common standard, but that's still technically an arbitrary choice, and may lead to interesting questions when invalid UTF8 sequences are encountered.

Say that you have a file called "\xc3\x28" (unescaped as C would unescape it). This is invalid UTF-8, so it can't be mapped to Unicode codepoint (AFAIK). How would you designate this path with a Java String? How would Java represent this as String if you were to list the contents of a directory containing said file?

@MrAnima is your question about the use of legacy encodings in a Linux filesystem, and how you'd manage that in Java?
